# How could an ecosystem remain stable for millions of years?

Tags: science-based, evolution, environment, fauna, dinosaurs

I am trying to create an isolated microcontinent where Cretaceous era dinosaurs/and maybe flora (specifically somewhere like Hell Creek) continues to survive with relatively little evolutionary difference (Similar to how platypus has remained relatively unchanged.) I want this area to essentially be the only landmass where non-avian dinosaurs are found as I want Cenozoic fauna in other areas of the planet. **My question is, how can this be done?** A KT-Extinction style event would stop photosynthesis so that's a no-go. I was thinking maybe disease or a smaller scale volcanism event (tiny Siberian Traps), that somehow doesn't affect said microcontinent. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: We're occasionally asked a question like this. With the [tag:science-based] tag in play, the answer is always "it can't be done, there isn't a way to scientifically stop evolution, adaptation, or mutation." You're choice is to take the Jules Verne option: declare it to be so as a rule of your world and move on with your story.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JBH Thanks for the comment! It helped me realize that I need to clarify that I'm not trying to halt evolution, moreso keep the ecosystem stable enough that the fauna/flora look relatively unchanged in a similar fashion to platypus and similar creatures that have changed little morphologically in the last 100+ million years.

Comment: But that's the problem: it's believable (not possible, but believable) to hold the temperature, rainfall, wind, etc., in an area to a very small amount of variation for millions of years... and you'd still have evolution, adaptation, and mutation. Humanity didn't evolve simply because the world changed around us and eventually we popped out. Every birth has a few differences. They still do! We're just getting better at working around or fixing those changes, which slows evolution down. The simple truth is, there's no scientific way to achieve what you're asking.

Comment: Also keep in mind that over millions of years the position of your geographic area literally changes. Islands are formed and destroyed. Whole continents move around. If you want to have some fun, check out [this map of the globe](https://dinosaurpictures.org/ancient-earth) that can be adjusted for different time periods. The one rule of science is that things change. And you're asking for a scientific way to stop that. This begs the question, how important is it to have a scientifically-defensible justification for your location?

Comment: BTW: I have not voted to close the question nor did I cast the down vote... but I'm not surprised to see either. This is a pretty tall order! You might consider using our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609) to perfect your questions before posting them on Main.

Comment: @JBH I think it might be possible. I'm not an expert but I believe basking sharks and whale sharks have survived relatively unchanged since the cretaceous. Admittedly keeeping a whole ecosystem unchanged is a lot less likely. If Cato is just looking for morphologically similar species that's a lot easier

Comment: @Bellerophon I thought of that, but every species I could remember scientists thinking had survived since antiquity... haven't (science has since proven they've evolved, too). But I'll give you credit for remembering oceanic critters. That's the only biome that could believably survive since landmasses move.

Comment: You might have a species survive without changes that are obvious without close study, but having all the thousands of species in an isolated ecosystem do so really doesn't make sense. Is that really necessary for what you want to achieve, though? Do you need the specific set of dinosaur species that lived together in a certain place at a certain time, or do you just need an ecosystem with surviving non-avian dinosaur genera?

Comment: Also, note that your setup is especially *unlikely* to avoid long-term changes. You're basically setting things up to demonstrate [Foster's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foster%27s_rule), for one thing.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I just need an ecosystem with surviving non-avian dinosaur genera. I don't need specifically T-Rex or Dakotaraptor, I'm moreso looking for ancestors of these clades to be existing while looking similar morphologically. Something like an ancestor of the Deinonychosaurians, Tyrannosaurs, etc. Or perhaps just later members of said clades.

Comment: @Bellerophon is correct, I'm primarily looking at ways to keep the ecosystem isolated and stable enough to justify a slowing down of morphological change for said population. It doesn't need to be unchanged as you said, just enough that the morphologies and recognizability of the clade/species is stabilized.

Comment: @Cato You don't need the environment to stay stable for some dinosaurs to survive, you just need a way for them to have survived the creation of the Deccan Traps and the asteroid hit. That is still a big problem but one that is far simpler.

Comment: Must the larger dinosaurs still exist?  if so you are going to have a problem that our atmosphere has less oxygen in it then it once had.  I think the largest non-avian dinosaurs would effectively suffocate in our current atmosphere; that's a problem hard to get around.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly easily actually, so long as you are just looking for modern dinosaurs that look and act relatively like cretaceous dinosaurs, and not a literal cessation to the mechanisms of evolution.  Modern crocodiles are quite physically and behaviorally similar to their cretaceous cousins, but if you had a DNA sample you'd be able to tell that they are very different organisms that have been subject to the same micro-level change over time as any other organism.  There is no halting the shuffling and shifting of genes over the eons, but you can create an environment where that shuffling and shifting is unlikely to move the needle too much on the macro scale just by creating a very stable environment.

Evolution moves inexorably forward, sure, but when the environment is stable and all the niches are filled, there isn't much benefit in deviating from how you already do things, and the risks of changing jobs while everyone else is optimizing can be substantial.  If the adaptations you already have are working, you will tend to lean into them and stay similar until they stop working.  The primary engine that drives major evolutionary change is the freeing up of niches, as happens after a mass extinction event.  The dinosaurs were around for longer than they have been gone.  They didn't just fade away because of the inevitable march of time.  The environment changed drastically, leading to them dying out and abandoning their niches, which, in turn, led to an explosion of diversification among mammal and bird species that were able to fill in those niches. If that mass extinction had never happened and the environment of the cretaceous remained constant, the dinosaurs would still be here, many probably looking quite similar to the way they did 65 million years ago.

The way to have a microclimate where the dinosaurs are still around is just to have a microclimate that hasn't changed since the Cretaceous.  Evolution will keep going, and how these dinosaurs differ from their ancestors would be an interesting thing to consider (likely options are things like becoming smaller or changes in things like coloration or behavior), but having a T-Rex as similar to its cretaceous ancestors as an alligator is to theirs wouldn't be a stretch at all in a mythical land isolated from the K/T mass extinction, where the environmental pressures that drove dinosaur extinction and mammal diversification elsewhere never happened.

Comment: What ways do you think  a microclimate could avoid an otherwise global extinction?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the limits of possibility are in your story.  Silurians shielded an island with lost tech?  The microclimate is the inside of the hollow earth?  If you are looking for something more inside the realm of possibility I think that if 1) the K/T event were less severe.  Maybe instead of a direct impact it was a near miss that broke off huge chunks that rained down on the earth, still kicking up a lot of dust but maybe making it possible for dinosaurs to eke out an existence in particularly rich equatorial environments.

Comment: and 2) a particular region was left free of mammals, allowing sub-optimal designs to retain their positions in their niches even when things were tough.  Animals have a tough time getting to islands so some remote island could concievably not have a mammal population (no birds are a harder sell because of the whole flight thing, but possible if remote enough, as flight designs weren't particularly optimized at this time.  I'm not sure if you had the equivalent of seagulls in bird form by K/T Day, though you definitely had pterysaurs filling that role).

Comment: You are left then with the question of how the dinosaurs got there, especially if you have a couple big ones, and it would have to be kind of a big island to support a population like that, but it's theoretically feasible.

Comment: Preferably the method of shielding said climate is more in the realm of possibility than something more sci-fi. I enjoy the idea of a close fly-by and I could perhaps even tie it in with the creation of a small planetary ring of some sort. I don't have an exceptional amount of freedom in the magic or tech department(at least not yet), but I do have freedom as being that this planet isn't actually *Earth*, it's just immensely Earth-like. I was thinking of making it a smaller microcontinent. Maybe the size of Madagascar if not a bit larger.